# Comparing text in a unit test

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I need to compare two lumps of text for any differences to ascertain whether my unit test has passed or not.  Unfortunately the text is about 500 characters long and if only one character differs it is very difficult to detect where the problem lies.  MSTest does not tell me which individual characters are different, it just tells me there is a difference.

What's the best way to compare text like this when unit testing?

*(I'm using MSTest (I would consider moving to NUnit but I'd rather not as all my tests have already been written in MSTest)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a library [Approval Tests](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/) specially designed for such scenarios. It supports both [mstest](/questions/tagged/mstest) and [nunit](/questions/tagged/nunit).

Library is build around "Golden Copy" testing approach — a trusted copy of a master data set, that you'll prepare and validate once

```
[TestClass]
public Tests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void LongTextTest()
    {
        // act: get long-long text
        string longText = GetLongText();

        //assert: will compare longText variable with file 
        //    Tests.LongTextTest.approved.txt
        // if there is some differences, 
        // it will start default diff tool to show actual differences
        Approvals.Verify(longText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Akim, gonna try this one out as I like the integration with Tortoise

Comment: It integrates with _default_ diff tool, in your case this could be TortoiseDiff. Anyway library worth looking at, if you are constantly working with long texts or images

Answer (score 2):

You may use MSTest `CollectionAssert` class.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTest()
{
    string strA = "Hello World";
    string strB = "Hello World";

    // OK
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(strA.ToCharArray(), strB.ToCharArray(), "Not equal!");

    //Uncomment that assert to see what error msg is when elements number differ
     //strA = "Hello Worl";
    //strB = "Hello World";
    //// Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException: CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. Not equal!(Different number of elements.)
    //CollectionAssert.AreEqual(strA.ToCharArray(), strB.ToCharArray(), "Not equal!");

    //Uncomment that assert to see what error msg is when elements are actually different
    //strA = "Hello World";
    //strB = "Hello Vorld";
    //// Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException: CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. Not equal!(Element at index 6 do not match.)
    //CollectionAssert.AreEqual(strA.ToCharArray(), strB.ToCharArray(), "Not equal!");

}
```

Comment: Hmmm, this is a little better possibly but all it tells me is there is are a different number of elements, not where that difference exists (about to try above now)

Comment: If there are diff number - it tells `Different number of elements`. If there are diff chars - it tells you where that diff exists `Element at index 6 do not match`. Actually you may push there your IComparer class that would write such info just like you want.

Comment: Where do I find that information?  All I see is Result Message: CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Different number of elements.)
Result StackTrace: at ShouldRenderKOPopoutShowFor() in HtmlHelpers\T_KOExtensions.cs:line 44

Comment: So all I get is the line number of the error and 'Different number of elements'.  Maybe I'm using MSTest incorrectly?  Is there a more detailed view of the error?

Comment: That is because your test fails on the second assert. Comment it - so that last assert may successfully fail.

Comment: Thanks Nikita, this is one type of solution but I'm gonna look for something a little bit more comprehensive

Answer (score 1):

Write a helper to do the comparison.

```
if(!String.Equals(textA, textB, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  int variesAtIndex = Utilities.DoByteComparison(textA,textB); // can be multiple, return -1 if all good
} // now assert on variesAtIndex`
```